# Converting new Date() to a format that includes T

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime, datetimepicker

**Background**

I have a datepicker (Angular UI) defined like this:

```
<date-picker name="contractEndDate" date="employee.contractEndDate"></date-picker>
```

The `contractEndDate` is set by a button click, changing it's value from `null` to *today*.

The date is set using this:

```
self.HandleEmployeeEndOfContract = function () {
    $scope.employee.contractEndDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
}
```

At the time of writing, that gives me:

```
26-1-2016 15:09:55
```

**What I need**

The `datepicker` needs the date as `26-1-2016T15:09:55` (notice the extra T). Setting `contractEndDate` to a date without the extra T, doesn't seem to work.

**Question**

Can I change the `.toLocaleString()` function to something that gives the date as above (incl. T)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is UTC format and you can achieve this using `new Date().toISOString();`

Comment: @Spikee, can you vote this as the rigth answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date().toISOString()
=> "2016-01-26T14:24:42.974Z"
```